# Ansible Unarchive leaving behind *.gz file instead of directory

Tags: ansible

I'm currently trying to implement an Ansible playbook to simply unarchive a .tar.gz or .tgz file. What I have currently implemented does unarchive the file, but leaves behind a .gz file instead of the directory that was archived. For example, I have testDirectory that contains testFile. I have compressed testDirectory into both testDirectory.tar.gz and testDirectory.tgz. When I run my playbook on either file, it untars the file leaving behind testDirectory.gz.

Here's my code:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - unarchive:
      src: '{directory}/testArchive.tar.gz'
      dest: '{directory}'
```

The goal is to simply unarchive the file, leaving behind {directory}/testArchive. What am I missing?

Comment: what happens when you untar it yourself? as `tar -C {directory} -zxvf {directory}/testArchive.tar.gz`

Comment: When I untar it myself, it does the same thing. Normally I manually gunzip and then untar. I thought that unarchive would do the same thing based on the file type. Is there a separate command for unzipping?

Comment: @Oshua, make sure the systems meet the [requirements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/unarchive_module.html#notes)

Comment: I guess the problem is about your package. Can you tar your package as `tar -czvf {directory}/testArchive.tar.gz {directory}/testDirectory` and then try your script again?

Answer (score 0):

`unarchive` does not handle .gz files per the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/unarchive_module.html)

There is [discussion](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/3241) of this issue from 2017 that references a future  `uncompress` module that does not appear to exist, and a statement by the maintainer that he was abandoning maintenance of the `unarchive` module.

A possible work around is: `command: gunzip filename.gz`